# change jspm_packages location

Tags: loader, ecmascript-6, jspm

Is there a `.bowerrc` equivalent in `jspm`? When I run `jspm install`, I'd like jspm to install the packages to `client/jspm_packages` folder.

How can I configure jspm to change location of jspm_packages folder?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this, so I'm not leaving it as an answer, but you may want to define the `jspm.main` property in your package.json file. See https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#prefixing-configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it. In your `package.json`, add the path into `packages` inside `directories`.

```
"jspm": {
  "directories": {
    "packages": "new/path/to/jspm_packages"
  }
}
```