# How to separate sources from dist files in Aurelia with JSPM?

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I am trying to use Aurelia with Symfony backend. Part of our application is generated on the backend (good, old server-side MVC) and part of it should be an SPA. I have started aurelia app from [skeleton-typescript](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript) (JSPM). Directory structure I am trying to create is as follows.

```
project/
  src/
    SomeModule/
    SomeOtherModule/
    FrontendModule/
      build/
      src/
        app.ts
        main.ts
        ...
      index.html
      package.json
      ...
  web/
    dist/
```

I have changed the output path in `build/paths.js` and `gulp build` correctly places the compiled files in the `web/dist`. I have also added a gulp task that copies the `index.html` into the `web/`.

The biggest problem I have is how to manage the JSPM dependencies. If I [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902646/change-jspm-packages-location) to downlad the dependencies into `web/jspm_dependencies`, the application works when launched with Symfony but I am not able to configure karma unit tests properly (it says for example that it can't find aurelia-polyfills). If I leave the `jspm_dependencies` in the `src/FrontendModule` then I have to create a gulp task that copies it to the `web/` and it takes a lot more than 10s => unacceptable.

This leds me to the following questions:

1. What is the suggested directory structure for Aurelia project when I am not going to serve the app from the project's root?
2. Is there any way to copy only the files needed by the application to the `web/` (something like [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) for bower)?

*I know I can `gulp export` the app into the `web/`, but I want to use the same directory structure during the development, too.*

*I don't want to use browsersync server in the dev because of multi-nature of the application (SPA part and non-SPA part that has to be served from "real" backend).*

Comment: Have you tried using `aurelia-cli` with the `asp.net core` option? This gives you a working setup where it's 1) not served from the project root, 2) does automatic differential re-bundling on any changes and 3) works with karma unit tests. That might put you on the right track.